# What is the best way to disable my WP website if the user has adblocker on?

Tags: conditional-content

What is the best way to disable my WP website if the user has adblocker on?

But at the same time let the user know why and what they need to do.

Comment: Read this article. https://www.labnol.org/internet/alternate-content-for-adblock/28602/

Comment: How is this specific to WP? Sounds like a more general webdev question to me. In general this is an arms race, which you are going to lose. Control on client side is inalienable part of how web works.

Comment: @Rarst, I'd like to know if there's a snippet that could detect the adblocker and allow some sort of conditional, that I could then apply to stop the user navigating further (mabe direct them to a page where I let them know.

Comment: @Ranuka, that's more replacing the ads with alternative content, i'm looking at a way that stops the user from using the website.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most plugins only give you the option to replace the ads with some other text but [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kill-adblock/) does the trick. If configured the right way you can work it so that a  whole screen popup appears with no option to disable it(no close button) other than turning off the browser's adblocker and reloading the page.

Comment: plugin recommendation without any actual explanation about how it works, is just not a worthy answer.

Comment: I did explain how it works, relevant to my question.

Comment: well, the most important part is how it detects the ad blockers, as before using such a thing you need to asses the amount of false positives and false negatives you might get. The rest can be coded around it. BTW if it just doing a popup above the content then it is easy to get around it, just delete the popup element....

Comment: 1. "... the most important part is how it detects the ad blockers..." Not to me. HOW it works wasn't part of my question. My question was the BEST way.
2. My users aren't as savvy as you so it's not easy for them to delete the popup.
3. you can see it working here https://perthreliefteachers.com.au/

Comment: the answer meeting what the poster asks for, is a minor factor in deciding if it is good or not. link only answer are rarely good.